# Using "SELF IN" with NSPredicate and RLMResults

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, realm

Based on the documentation in https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/, 
I'm trying to use SELF to query some data in the realm class but I keep on getting an RLMException `Predicate with IN operator must compare a KeyPath with an aggregate with two values`

The solution I can think of so far is to iterate over the objects and get their ID's and then use the ID's in the `NSPredicate` condition, this solution was supported here [NSPredicate using RLMResults as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759737/nspredicate-using-rlmresults-as-an-argument) but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way using the keyword `SELF`.

Note: I tried using `ANY` in my `NSPredicate` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` but it also failed.

```
 (void)deleteOldOfferObjects : (RLMResults *) newOfferObjects{

    NSPredicate *oldObjects = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", newOfferObjects];

    RLMResults *oldObjectsArr =[Offer objectsWithPredicate:oldObjects];

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    [realm deleteObjects:oldObjectsArr];

    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently do not support `SELF` in that context so you are correct that you should iterate over a collection of primary keys.